# sql and php - is there ant issue with this query or code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

hi guys here is my update function it takes some parameters and eveluates them if they are integer or string after that process the values and throws for query sentence...

```
public function update ($table, $cols, $values, $addition) {
    $db = $this->connect();
    $i = 0;
    $update = '';
    if ((is_array($cols)) && (is_array($values))) {
        foreach ($cols as $a) {
            if (!is_int($values[$i])) {
                $update = $a.'="'.$values[$i].'",';
            } else {
                $update = $a.'='.$values[$i].',';
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $update = substr($update, 0, -1);
    } else {
        if (!is_int($values)) {
            $update = $cols.'="'.$values.'",';
        } else {
            $update = $cols.'='.$values.',';
        }
    }
    echo "update ".$table." set ".$update." ".$addition."<br>";
    try {
        $sql = $db->prepare("update ".$table." set ".$update." ".$addition);
        $sql->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
    $db = null;
}
```

and here are the parameters and the sql query

```
$this->db->update("brands", "car_count", $brandCarCount[0]+1, "where brand = '".$brand."'");

update brands set car_count=2, where brand = 'alfa_romeo'
```

i really do not understand what happens, i can not find the problem. it works for other inserting selecting or deleting functions.

i need help!

Comment: You got superfluous comma there (the one before where)

Comment: ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff @Reto i will leave this place

Comment: no problem, sometimes we cant see the wood because of the trees ;)

Answer (score 1):

That is the relevant line which removes the trailing comma:

> $update = rtrim($update,',');

and this is the full code:

```
public function update ($table, $cols, $values, $addition) {
    $db = $this->connect();
    $i = 0;
    $update = '';
    if ((is_array($cols)) && (is_array($values))) {
        foreach ($cols as $a) {
            if (!is_int($values[$i])) {
                $update = $a.'="'.$values[$i].'",';
            } else {
                $update = $a.'='.$values[$i].',';
            }
            $i++;
        }
    } else {
        if (!is_int($values)) {
            $update = $cols.'="'.$values.'",';
        } else {
            $update = $cols.'='.$values.',';
        }
    }
    $update = rtrim($update,',');
    echo "update ".$table." set ".$update." ".$addition."<br>";
    try {
        $sql = $db->prepare("update ".$table." set ".$update." ".$addition);
        $sql->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }
    $db = null;
}
```